# Mastermind Python problem for correct colour and correct place and correct colour and wrong place

Tags: python

Hi Below is my master mind game python code, now I have a problem that example: when the answer is "RGRG" and I enter the alphabet "GRRG" by right the output for Correct colour and correct place should be = 2 and Correct colour and wrong place should be = 2. but now the output is wrong and it shows that colour and correct place = 2 but Correct colour and wrong place = 0. So if anybody know what part of my code is wrong?

```
import random
from random import choice

print("Welcome to Chee Fung Mastermind Games")
opening = input("Hi Do you need instruction or starightly enter into the game. [I/G]\n")
if opening == "I" or opening == "i" :
        print("Computer will automatically generate four colour from list.")
        print("Player must guess 4 colours numbers correct from the list to win the game.")
        print("You have 10 times chances to atempt the game.")
        print("There will be 5 colours in the below list.")
        print("(R)Red, (G)Green, (B)Blue, (P)Purple, (O)Orange")
        print("Player no need to enter the whole word, just need to enter the first alphabetical of the colours.")
        print("Example: for Red colour you just need to enter 'r' or 'R'.")
else:
        print("Let's start the game.")
prev_curt_color = 0
colors = ["R", "G", "B", "Y", "W", "P"]
attempts = 0
game = True

# computer randomly picks four-color code
color_code = []
for i in range(4):
        color_code.append(choice(colors))
print (color_code)


# player guesses the number
while game:
        correct_color = 0
        guessed_color = 0
        player_guess = input("Please enter the four colour:").upper()
        attempts += 1
        # checking if player's input is correct
        if len(player_guess) != len(color_code):
                print ("\nThe color code has exactly four colors. please try again!")
                attempts -= 1
                continue
        for i in range(4):
                if player_guess[i] not in colors:
                        print ("\nLook up what colors you can use in this game.")
                        attempts -= 1
                        break
        # comparison between player's input and secret code and player_guess[i] in color_code
        if correct_color != 4:
                for i in range(4):
                        if player_guess[i] == color_code[i]:
                                correct_color += 1
                        elif player_guess[i] != color_code[i] and player_guess[i] in color_code and correct_color > prev_curt_color:
                                guessed_color += 1
                        prev_curt_color = correct_color
                print("Correct colour and correct place: ", correct_color)
                print("Correct colour and wrong place: ", guessed_color)

        if correct_color == 4:
                if attempts == 1:
                        print ("Wow! You guessed at the first attempt!")
                else:
                        print ("Well done... You needed " + str(attempts) + " attempts to guess.")
                game = False

        if attempts >= 1 and attempts <10 and correct_color != 4:
                print("The attempt time " + str(attempts))
                print("Next attempt: ")
        elif attempts >= 10:
                print ("You didn't guess! The secret color code was: " + str(color_code))
                game = False

        # play or not to play
        while game == False:
                finish_game = input("\nDo you want to play again (Y/N)?").upper()
                attempts = 0
                if finish_game =="N":
                        print ("Thanks for the game! Bye, bye!")
                        break
                elif finish_game == "Y":
                        game = True
                        print ("So, let's play again... Guess the secret code: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed your code and debug it. then I found a problem when your `color_code = ['R','G','G','G']` and `player_guess ='GGGG'` when the program first time try to compare `correct_color` with `prev_curt_color`. they're both equal to 0. so when you want to figure out the numbers of Correct colour and wrong place. It will shows 0 instead of 1.
here is the edited code down below.

```
    if correct_color != 4:
    for i in range(4):
        if player_guess[i] == color_code[i]:
            correct_color += 1
            prev_curt_color = correct_color
        elif player_guess[i] != color_code[i] and player_guess[
                i] in color_code and correct_color >= prev_curt_color:
            guessed_color += 1
```

BTW, It seems that you should learn about how to debug a python program here is a tutorial, I hope it can help
[Debug Tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html#where-is-the-problem)

Comment: ya, but I need to let the colour code choose randomly by computer instead of using color_code = ['R','G','G','G']

Comment: You can give it a try, it can work no matter what color_code is!

Comment: can you update the whole code for me haha, cause i have a little bit confused haha

Comment: now If i follow your code, i have a problem that is when the computer automatically generate the color_code is [W, P, P, R] and if user input is RRRR by right the answer should be Correct colour and correct place : 2 and Correct colour and wrong place: 0 but now my output is  Correct colour and correct place : 2 and Correct colour and wrong place: 2

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from random import choice

print("Welcome to Chee Fung Mastermind Games")
opening = input(
    "Hi Do you need instruction or starightly enter into the game. [I/G]\n")
if opening == "I" or opening == "i":
    print("Computer will automatically generate four colour from list.")
    print(
        "Player must guess 4 colours numbers correct from the list to win the game."
    )
    print("You have 10 times chances to atempt the game.")
    print("There will be 5 colours in the below list.")
    print("(R)Red, (G)Green, (B)Blue, (P)Purple, (O)Orange")
    print(
        "Player no need to enter the whole word, just need to enter the first alphabetical of the colours."
    )
    print("Example: for Red colour you just need to enter 'r' or 'R'.")
else:
    print("Let's start the game.")
prev_curt_color = 0
colors = ["R", "G", "B", "Y", "W", "P"]
attempts = 0
game = True

# computer randomly picks four-color code
color_code = []
for i in range(4):
    color_code.append(choice(colors))
print(color_code)

# player guesses the number
while game:
    correct_color = 0
    guessed_color = 0
    player_guess = input("Please enter the four colour:").upper()
    attempts += 1
    color_dict={}
    # checking if player's input is correct
    if len(player_guess) != len(color_code):
        print("\nThe color code has exactly four colors. please try again!")
        attempts -= 1
        continue
    for i in range(4):
        if player_guess[i] not in color_dict: 
            color_dict.update({'{}'.format(player_guess[i]):1})
        else:
            color_dict.update({'{}'.format(player_guess[i]):color_dict.get(player_guess[i]+1)})
        if player_guess[i] not in colors:
            print("\nLook up what colors you can use in this game.")
            attempts -= 1
            break
    # comparison between player's input and secret code and player_guess[i] in color_code
    if correct_color != 4:
        
        for i in range(4):
            if player_guess[i] == color_code[i] and color_dict.get(player_guess[i]) >= 1:
                correct_color += 1
            elif player_guess[i] != color_code[i] and color_dict.get(player_guess[i]) >1:
                pass
            elif player_guess[i] != color_code[i] and color_dict.get(player_guess[i]) ==1:
                guessed_color += 1
        print("Correct colour and correct place: ", correct_color)
        print("Correct colour and wrong place: ", guessed_color)

    if correct_color == 4:
        if attempts == 1:
            print("Wow! You guessed at the first attempt!")
        else:
            print("Well done... You needed " + str(attempts) +
                  " attempts to guess.")
        game = False

    if attempts >= 1 and attempts < 10 and correct_color != 4:
        print("The attempt time " + str(attempts))
        print("Next attempt: ")
    elif attempts >= 10:
        print("You didn't guess! The secret color code was: " +
              str(color_code))
        game = False

    # play or not to play
    while game == False:
        finish_game = input("\nDo you want to play again (Y/N)?").upper()
        attempts = 0
        if finish_game == "N":
            print("Thanks for the game! Bye, bye!")
            break
        elif finish_game == "Y":
            game = True
            print("So, let's play again... Guess the secret code: ")
```